# mysql select all X in column A where column B = Y

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table where I am trying to find all words that belong to the same category. The table looks like this:

```
ID |  CATEGORY  | word
---------------------
1  |  2         | elephant
2  |  2         | lion
3  |  5         | duck
4  |  5         | pig
5  |  5         | chicken
6  |  7         | shark
7  |  7         | whale
8  |  7         | dolphin
9  |  7         | bass
```

So if someone searches for "lion" I should get all the animals in that category. 
How would one perform this without running 2 queries, one to select from column "word" the animal and then run another select query for all the animals that are in the previously found category?

Comment: The answer to the question 'Is there a way...' is yes. But it's not an appropriate question.

Comment: Side note: `GROUP` is an SQL keyword. Better avoid using it as a column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some other ways to do it but I will do this :

```
SELECT t1.word
FROM
table t1
INNER Join
table t2 on t2.group = t1.group
WHERE t2.word = 'lion'
```

Nota : try to avoid Names like 'group', 'select', etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using a subquery as shown below:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE `group` IN (SELECT `group` FROM yourTable 
                  WHERE `word`='lion');
```

Comment: This is still 2 queries smushed into one.

Comment: @Sandor it's one query with 1 subequery ;)

Comment: I know, I was hoping for a magical one liner query that does not need joins or subqueries, but it looks like that there is no such thing in MySQL. I do realize that any answer I've got is much better than running 2 separate select queries because they represent only one request to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name.word FROM table_name 
WHERE table_name.GROUP in (select group from table_name where word ='loin');
```